# Expression with parameter (LINQ, SQL,C#)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

i struggling to find the correct way to query for a specific entity in my database. I have a table TeamMember which looks as follows:

```
public class TeamMember
{
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }
    public Guid ManagerUserId  { get; set; }
    ...       
}
```

At several positions i want to query for a "TeamManager" in my teams.

```
public TeamMember GetTeamManager(Guid teamId, List<TeamMember> teamMembers)
{
    return teamMembers.FirstOrDefault(member => member.TeamId == teamId && member.ManagerUserId == null);
}
```

If i want to use a method in an expression e.g (not real code),

```
...
// IQueryable<TeamMember>
teamMembers.Where(member => member.team.GetTeamManager(teamId, teamMembers))
```

it works fine for in memory objects, but this does not work in combination with the entity framework, so real db objects.

Therefore i was experimenting with static expressions, but i did not find any solution which uses a static expression in combination with a variable e.g.:

```
// this should be an ideal solution
Expression<Func<TeamMember, bool>> exp = teammember => teamMember.TeamId == **CUSTOM_VARIABLE** && teamMember.ManagerUserId == null;

teamMembers.Where(exp)
```

I want to reuse the expression, but i also want to be able to modify the variable. My goal is to avoid the creation of an object in between because the following would work, but is less efficient (correct me if i'm wrong)

```
teamMembers.ToList().Where(member => member.team.GetTeamManager(teamId, teamMembers))
```

So please help me with my problem :).
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make `exp` a property because of the need to capture a variable, but you can make it a function returning `Expression<Func<TeamMember,bool>>`:

```
Expression<Func<TeamMember,bool>> MakeMemberExpression(Guid teamId) {
    return teammember => teamMember.TeamId == teamId && teamMember.ManagerUserId == null;
}
```

or even

```
Expression<Func<TeamMember,bool>> MakeMemberExpression(Guid teamId) =>
    teammember => teamMember.TeamId == teamId && teamMember.ManagerUserId == null;
```

You can use it as follows:

```
var members = teamMembers.Where(MakeMemberExpression(teamId));
```

Comment: Thanks works as intended, i tried something similar but got lost somewhere. Maybe i should point out, that this only works with IQueryable elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that operates on IQueryable.

```
public TeamMember GetTeamManager(IQueryable<TeamMember> baseQuery,Guid teamId)
{
    return baseQuery.FirstOrDefault(member => member.TeamId == teamId && member.ManagerUserId == null);
}
```